# php fetching data using jquery without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am fetching data from mysql db using jquery. The problem is I want the data from php in seprated form, like separte field for roll number, name and father name from php. Look at the code

html and jquery:

```
<div id="Name"> </div>
<div id="Fname"> </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script> 
$('input#rsubmit').on('click', function () {
var rnum = $('input#rollno').val();
  if ($.trim(rnum) != ''){
      $.post('newdata.php', {rnum: rnum}, function(data){
          $('div#Name').text(data);
      });
  }
});
</script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['rnum']) === true && empty($_POST['rnum']) === false){

$rollno = $_POST['rnum'];
$query = $con->query("select * from students where RollNo='$rollno'");
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result == true){
    echo "Name: ".$result['Name'];
    echo "Father Name: ".$result['FatherName'];
}else{
    echo "No result found";
}


}
```

The problem is that i want Name and Father Name in separate div's. Currently it gives both Name and Father Name in #name div

Comment: Return a json array from your php script, parse it and put each variable where you want...

Comment: @ДејанИгњатов is correct. try json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning json from php.

```
$user = array();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$user['name'] = $result['name'];
$user['father_name'] = $result['FatherName'];


echo json_encode($user);
```

It will return [{name:'abc', father_name:'xyz'}]
Now you can access this json data wherever you want.

Comment: how can i access this array in jquery?

Comment: jsondata = JSON.parse(response);

$('div#Name').text(jsondata[0].name);
$('div#Name').text(jsondata[0].Fname)

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP as below

```
if (isset($_POST['rnum']) === true && empty($_POST['rnum']) === false){
        $rollno = $_POST['rnum'];
        $query = $con->query("select * from students where RollNo='$rollno'");

        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($result == true){
            echo json_encode($result);
        }else{
            echo json_encode('No Records found');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP:
if ($result == true){
    echo json_encode(array('name'=> $result['Name'], 'father' => $result['FatherName']));

}else{
```

and

```
JS: 
$.post('newdata.php', {rnum: rnum}, function(data){
      $('div#Name').text(data.name);
      $('div#Fname').text(data.father);
  });
```

Comment: Not working , if i change code like this $('div#Name').text(data);  then it gives output like this: {"name":"Imran","father":"Muhammad Aslam"}